# Why isn't my music showing up under Storage in About This Mac?

Tags: music, storage, macos

I have 25 GB of music on my Mac but for some reason when I click on About This Mac and click on Storage, it doesn't show any music.

[image]

I can see the music in my iTunes media folder when I go into Finder on right click on Music:

[image]

Any suggestion on why this is not showing up on About This Mac? iTunes seems to work fine and the fact that Finder shows the music makes me confident that it's there but just a little concerned that it's not showing up under Storage in About This Mac.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just for clarification, your music is visible in both Finder and iTunes (you can the songs) but you're concerned because it's not showing up as its own section in 'About this Mac'?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Comment: Is it supposed to display a section there?  I don't see it on my MacBook Pro.  As long as the music is there, you can see it in Finder, and you can play it in iTunes, why are you worried about the About this Mac display?  I guess that's why I'm still a little confused.

Comment: I agree with your comment. Maybe I don't care but I was pretty sure it used to show in that section so I thought it might be a symptom of a bigger issue

Comment: 1. If your music it there and it plays then there is absolutely nothing to worry about. 2. On my system, which at the moment has no documents, just 8 GB of music, macOS Sierra is incorrectly displaying the music as Documents under Storage in About This Mac. macOS has issues and bugs just like every OS release regardless of what OS it is! A question to you, do you actually have the amount of Photos as shown in the screen shot?